# How to push image on the battery?

Tags: android

In my application, I want to push the image on the battery, and on the image, I want to show the battery icon, time and wifi signal [image]

Is it possible to do that?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Try [Notifications](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification)

Your best bet is to use Notifications in Android to show your message on the status bar

Comment: I want to cover it from the application not from the notifications.